# Google Maps API: Total distance with waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to calculate the total distance for a route with a single waypoint in it, but somehow my code only returns the distance to the first waypoint instead of the total distance.

Here's my code:

```
function calcRoute(homebase,from,to,via){
var start = from;
var end = to;
var wypt = [ ];
wypt.push({
            location:via,
            stopover:true});

var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    waypoints:wypt,     
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

    var distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text; 
    var time_taken = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text; 

    var calc_distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value; 
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you only get the distance for legs[0] is because that is what your code is calculating.  You need to sum up the distances of all the legs:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_totalDist.html

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
    // from: Blackpool to: Preston to: Blackburn
    origin: "Blackpool,UK",
    destination: "Blackburn,UK",
    waypoints: [{
      location: "Preston,UK",
      stopover: true
    }],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
      }
      computeTotalDistance(response);
    } else {
      alert("directions response " + status);
    }
  });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var totalDist = 0;
  var totalTime = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
  totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "total distance is: " + totalDist + " km<br>total time is: " + (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2) + " minutes";
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
<div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
  <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
  <div id="total"></div>
</div>
```