# set google origin search box address with a variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make origin SearchBox destination be string with legit direction, but when I do so I still need to select the first option for it to work (to calculate distance).

Got the this searching around to calculate distance between 2 points and it works perfectly:
[How can I add multiple searchBoxes in my google maps api web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004728/how-can-i-add-multiple-searchboxes-in-my-google-maps-api-web/59009704#59009704)

I got a string for example: albrook mall which I know exist (this string is dynamic is coming from a variable and all address are validated. get the needed address pass it to a variable so I can read it on the frontEnd, and set the value of search box in the html. the value is updated with jquery

[image]

But what happens is that I still have to click on the origin search box then this list all possible locations which in my case is the first one, how can I make the map either auto select the first option or recognize the address that is set in the input value?

```
    <script>

   function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  center: {
  lat: 9.0271554,
   lng: 79.4816371
         },
         zoom: 15
        });

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     draggable: false
   });


      if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  map.setCenter(initialLocation);
         /*marker.setPosition(initialLocation);         */
         });
        }

      new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      }

       /**
       * @constructor
       */
       function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
       this.map = map;
       this.originPlaceId = null;
         this.destinationPlaceId = null;
         this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
      this.avoidTolls = true;
        this.avoidHighways= true;
          //this.provideRouteAlternatives= true,
          this.avoidFerries= true;
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
       this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
           this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

              var originInput = document.getElementById('orign');
           var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destn');

            var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(originInput);

          var destinationAutocomplete =
           new google.maps.places.SearchBox(destinationInput);

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

          }

          AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
          autocomplete, mode) {
       var me = this;
       autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

       autocomplete.addListener('places_changed', function() {
     var places = autocomplete.getPlaces();
         var place = places[0];

    if (!place.place_id) {
    window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
  return;
     }
       if (mode === 'ORIG') {
         me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
        }
        me.route();
       });
      };

          AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
  }
     var me = this;

     this.directionsService.route({
  origin: {
    'placeId': this.originPlaceId
  },
  destination: {
    'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
  },
  travelMode: this.travelMode,
  avoidTolls: this.avoidTolls
   },
   function(response, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    computeTotalDistance(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
    });
    };
    // from Google Maps API: Total distance with waypoints
   // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802202/google-maps-api-total-distance-with-waypoints
    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
     var totalDist = 0;
    var totalTime = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
     for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
     totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
      }
       totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
      time = (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2)

  document.getElementById("totalkm").innerHTML ="" + totalDist + "km" ;
  document.getElementById("totaltime").innerHTML ="" + time  + " minutos";

 if(totalDist <= 5){
   document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML =" $3.50";
  }

 else{
 kmPrice = (totalDist - 5) * 0.75;
 document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML ="$" +(kmPrice + 3.50).toFixed(2)+ "";

     }
    }

   function send_handle(){
   let name=document.getElementById("name").value;
 ///let lastname= document.getElementById("lastname").value;
 let inst= document.getElementById("instructions").value;
 let origin= document.querySelector(".selectButtons input#orign").value;
let destination= document.querySelector(".selectButtons input#destn").value;
let cost= document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML;
let distance= document.getElementById("totalkm").innerHTML;
    // win.focus();
     }
    </script>


           
    <html>
   <div class="selectButtons" >
   <input type="text" id="orign" placeholder="origen">
   <input type="text" id="destn" placeholder="destino">
   <span> Distancia en KM <div id="totalkm">0km</div> </span>
   <span> Distancia en tiempo <div id="totaltime">o.oo</div> </span>
   <span> costo por envio<div id="totalCost">$0</div></div> </span>
   </div>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the places service to get the PlaceId (with your string), then pass that placeId into the constructor for your `AutocompleteDirectionsHandler` or if you already have the `PlaceId` (you are allowed to store those), just use it, although you probably want to initialize the origin input with the string.

```
  var origin = "Allbrook, Panama";
  var originInput = document.getElementById('orign');
  originInput.value = origin;
  const request = {
    query: origin,
    fields: ["name", "geometry", "place_id"],
  };
  var originPlaceId;
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK && results) {
      originPlaceId = results[0].place_id;
      console.log("placeId="+originPlaceId+" coords="+results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
      new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map, originPlaceId);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
```

Add the initial origin placeId to the `AutocompleteDirectionsHandler` constructor:

```
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map, originPlaceId) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = originPlaceId;
  // ...
```

**on load:**
[image: screenshot on load]

**after selecting destination from dropdown:**
[image: screenshot after fill in destination]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 9.0271554,
      lng: 79.4816371
    },
    zoom: 15
  });

  var origin = "Allbrook, Panama";
  var originInput = document.getElementById('orign');
  originInput.value = origin;
  const request = {
    query: origin,
    fields: ["name", "geometry", "place_id"],
  };
  var originPlaceId;
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK && results) {
      originPlaceId = results[0].place_id;
      console.log("placeId="+originPlaceId+" coords="+results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
      new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map, originPlaceId);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: false
  });


  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
      /*marker.setPosition(initialLocation);         */
    });
  }
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map, originPlaceId) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = originPlaceId;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
  this.avoidTolls = true;
  this.avoidHighways = true;
  //this.provideRouteAlternatives= true,
  this.avoidFerries = true;
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  this.directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  var originInput = document.getElementById('orign');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destn');

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(originInput);

  var destinationAutocomplete =
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(destinationInput);

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

}

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
  autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

  autocomplete.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = autocomplete.getPlaces();
    var place = places[0];

    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    }
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;

  this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        'placeId': this.originPlaceId
      },
      destination: {
        'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId
      },
      travelMode: this.travelMode,
      avoidTolls: this.avoidTolls
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        computeTotalDistance(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
};
// from Google Maps API: Total distance with waypoints
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802202/google-maps-api-total-distance-with-waypoints
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var totalDist = 0;
  var totalTime = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
  }
  totalDist = totalDist / 1000.
  time = (totalTime / 60).toFixed(2)

  document.getElementById("totalkm").innerHTML = "" + totalDist + "km";
  document.getElementById("totaltime").innerHTML = "" + time + " minutos";

  if (totalDist <= 5) {
    document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML = " $3.50";
  } else {
    kmPrice = (totalDist - 5) * 0.75;
    document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML = "$" + (kmPrice + 3.50).toFixed(2) + "";

  }
}

function send_handle() {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  ///let lastname= document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  let inst = document.getElementById("instructions").value;
  let origin = document.querySelector(".selectButtons input#orign").value;
  let destination = document.querySelector(".selectButtons input#destn").value;
  let cost = document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML;
  let distance = document.getElementById("totalkm").innerHTML;
  // win.focus();
}


function createMarker(place) {
  if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) return;

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name || "");
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="selectButtons">
  <input type="text" id="orign" placeholder="origen" />
  <input type="text" id="destn" placeholder="destino" />
  <span> Distancia en KM <div id="totalkm">0km</div> </span>
  <span> Distancia en tiempo <div id="totaltime">o.oo</div> </span>
  <span> costo por envio<div id="totalCost">$0</div> </span>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</html>
```